# OleDbDataReader throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to read a single line out of my database with a special number.
If i want to write this line in some textboxes, i get a NullReferenceException error. The line is definetly filled in my database.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select Kundennummer, Kundenname, Firmenbuchnummer, Email, Telefon1, Telefon2, Fax, Website, UID, IBAN, BIC, Strasse, PLZ, Ort, Land, Notizen from tbl_Kunden where Kundennummer = @knr", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@knr", OleDbType.Integer, 10);
cmd.Parameters["@knr"].Value = knr;
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    txtNr.Text = rdr[0].ToString();....
```

Comment: `rdr[0]` is null for at least one of your records.

Comment: Filled all null values, but it is still not working..

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to be certain?

Comment: Where can i find the value of rdr[0]?